# kubernetes dashboard not working: Error: 'EOF,Trying to reach: 'http://10.10.85.2:53/'

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, kube-dns

I used the binary package to install kubernetes master ha on centos 7, Three master nodes and three minions

I followed this guide [coredns](https://github.com/coredns/deployment/tree/master/kubernetes) to install a kube-dns and  `./deploy.sh 10.100.0.0/16 cluster.local | kubectl apply -f -`

the last, the dashboard not working and got the error as below：

> Error: 'EOF' Trying to reach: 'http://10.10.85.2:53/'

on the master:

```
[root@iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ ~]# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.2.93:6443
CoreDNS is running at https://192.168.2.93:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

[root@iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ ~]# systemctl status kube-apiserver -l
● kube-apiserver.service - Kubernetes API Server
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kube-apiserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-08-09 13:34:40 CST; 20h ago
      Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview
Main PID: 25178 (kube-apiserver)
  CGroup: /system.slice/kube-apiserver.service
       └─25178 /usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver --storage-backend=etcd3 --etcd-servers=http://192.168.2.86:2379,http://192.168.2.87:2379,http://192.168.2.88:2379 --insecure-bind-address=192.168.2.86 --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --secure-port=6443 --service-cluster-ip-range=10.100.0.0/16 --service-node-port-range=30000-65535 --enable-bootstrap-token-auth --token-auth-file=/etc/kubernetes/token.csv --basic-auth-file=/etc/kubernetes/basic_auth_file --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubernetes.pem --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubernetes-key.pem --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca-key.pem --enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota --logtostderr=false --log-dir=/var/log/kubernetes --v=0 --allow-privileged=true

Aug 09 13:34:35 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ kube-apiserver[25178]: [restful] 2018/08/09 13:34:35 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] https://192.168.2.86:6443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
Aug 09 13:34:36 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ kube-apiserver[25178]: [restful] 2018/08/09 13:34:36 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://192.168.2.86:6443/swaggerapi
Aug 09 13:34:36 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ kube-apiserver[25178]: [restful] 2018/08/09 13:34:36 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] https://192.168.2.86:6443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
Aug 09 13:34:40 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes API Server.
Aug 09 13:51:58 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ kube-apiserver[25178]: E0809 13:51:58.130303   25178 watcher.go:208] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
Aug 09 14:04:45 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ kube-apiserver[25178]: E0809 14:04:45.138555   25178 watcher.go:208] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
Aug 09 14:18:44 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ kube-apiserver[25178]: E0809 14:18:44.195958   25178 watcher.go:208] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted

[root@iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ ~]# systemctl status kube-controller-manager -l
● kube-controller-manager.service
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kube-controller-manager.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-08-09 09:49:48 CST; 24h ago
Main PID: 18963 (kube-controller)
  CGroup: /system.slice/kube-controller-manager.service
       └─18963 /usr/local/bin/kube-controller-manager --address=127.0.0.1 --master=http://192.168.2.86:8080 --cluster-name=kubernetes --cluster-signing-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem --cluster-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca-key.pem --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca-key.pem --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem --leader-elect=true --v=0

Aug 09 14:04:45 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ kube-controller-manager[18963]: W0809 14:04:45.138760   18963 reflector.go:341] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:130: watch of *v1beta1.Event ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
Aug 09 14:09:19 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ kube-controller-manager[18963]: I0809 14:09:19.828878   18963 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Deployment", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"kubernetes-dashboard", UID:"c0e38fdd-9b9a-11e8-9209-00163e025f2f", APIVersion:"apps/v1", ResourceVersion:"83360", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'ScalingReplicaSet' Scaled up replica set kubernetes-dashboard-c7496bcf to 1
Aug 09 14:09:19 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ kube-controller-manager[18963]: I0809 14:09:19.839412   18963 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ReplicaSet", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"kubernetes-dashboard-c7496bcf", UID:"c0e4332b-9b9a-11e8-80b3-00163e0e0d6d", APIVersion:"apps/v1", ResourceVersion:"83361", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'SuccessfulCreate' Created pod: kubernetes-dashboard-c7496bcf-b28rr
Aug 10 02:24:59 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ kube-controller-manager[18963]: W0810 02:24:59.348618   18963 reflector.go:341] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:130: watch of *v1beta1.Event ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
Aug 10 04:20:01 iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ kube-controller-manager[18963]: W0810 04:20:01.448973   18963 reflector.go:341] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:130: watch of *v1beta1.Event ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.

[root@iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME                      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
izuf68thdbm0n4j5qywd7qz   Ready     <none>    22h       v1.11.0
izuf68thdbm0n4j5qywd7rz   Ready     <none>    22h       v1.11.0
izuf68thdbm0n4j5qywd7sz   Ready     <none>    23h       v1.11.0

[root@iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ ~]# kubectl get cs
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE              ERROR
controller-manager   Healthy   ok                   
scheduler            Healthy   ok                   
etcd-1               Healthy   {"health": "true"}   
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health": "true"}   
etcd-2               Healthy   {"health": "true"} 

[root@iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ ~]# kubectl get -o wide pods -n kube-system 
NAME                                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE      IP           NODE
coredns-5b6cd55cf8-6tjdl              1/1       Running   1          22h       10.10.85.2   izuf68thdbm0n4j5qywd7sz
kubernetes-dashboard-c7496bcf-b28rr   1/1       Running   0          19h      10.10.85.3   izuf68thdbm0n4j5qywd7sz

[root@iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ ~]# kubectl get endpoints -n kube-system
NAME                      ENDPOINTS                     AGE
kube-controller-manager   <none>                        1d
kube-dns                  10.10.85.2:53,10.10.85.2:53   22h
kube-scheduler            <none>                        1d
kubernetes-dashboard      10.10.85.3:8443               19h

[root@iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ ~]# telnet 10.10.85.2 53
Trying 10.10.85.2...
Connected to 10.10.85.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

on the minion izuf68thdbm0n4j5qywd7sz:

```
# systemctl status kubelet -l
● kubelet.service - Kubernetes API Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-08-09 12:38:43 CST; 21h ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/doc
 Main PID: 3444 (kubelet)
    Memory: 49.2M
    CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
       └─3444 /usr/local/bin/kubelet --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.kubeconfig --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap.kubeconfig --logtostderr=false --log-dir=/var/log/kubernetes --v=0 --cluster-dns=10.100.0.100 --cluster-domain=cluster.local. --resolv-conf=/etc/resolv.conf

Aug 10 09:56:26 iZuf68thdbm0n4j5qywd7sZ kubelet[3444]: E0810 09:56:26.924371    3444 streamwatcher.go:109] Unable to decode an event from the watch stream: stream error: stream ID 43959; INTERNAL_ERROR
Aug 10 09:56:26 iZuf68thdbm0n4j5qywd7sZ kubelet[3444]: E0810 09:56:26.924370    3444 streamwatcher.go:109] Unable to decode an event from the watch stream: stream error: stream ID 43961; INTERNAL_ERROR

[root@iZuf68thdbm0n4j5qywd7sZ ~]# systemctl status kube-proxy -l
● kube-proxy.service - Kubernetes kubelet agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kube-proxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-08-09 12:38:51 CST; 21h ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/doc
Main PID: 3525 (kube-proxy)
  Memory: 5.2M
  CGroup: /system.slice/kube-proxy.service
       ‣ 3525 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kube-proxy.kubeconfig --proxy-mode=iptables --cluster-cidr=10.100.0.0/16

Aug 10 09:57:35 iZuf68thdbm0n4j5qywd7sZ kube-proxy[3525]: E0810 09:57:35.383308    3525 streamwatcher.go:109] Unable to decode an event from the watch stream: stream error: stream ID 2981; INTERNAL_ERROR
Aug 10 09:58:35 iZuf68thdbm0n4j5qywd7sZ kube-proxy[3525]: E0810 09:58:35.496183    3525 streamwatcher.go:109] Unable to decode an event from the watch stream: stream error: stream ID 2983; INTERNAL_ERROR
```

get service on the master:

```
[root@iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ ~]# kubectl get service -o wide -n kube-system
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         
AGE       SELECTOR
kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.100.0.100    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   1d        k8s-app=coredns
kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.100.226.37   <none>        443/TCP         2d        k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard

[root@iZuf69az6mflbck93u847cZ ~]# kubectl get deployment kubernetes- dashboard -o yaml -n kube-system
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: 2018-08-10T05:38:45Z
  generation: 1
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "236080"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments/kubernetes-dashboard
  uid: a5eaaf89-9c5f-11e8-9209-00163e025f2f
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
  k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --auto-generate-certificates
        image: reg.xxx.cn/pub/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.8.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 8443
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 30
        name: kubernetes-dashboard
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /certs
          name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp-volume
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: kubernetes-dashboard
      serviceAccountName: kubernetes-dashboard
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
      volumes:
      - name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: tmp-volume
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-08-10T05:38:45Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2018-08-10T05:38:47Z
    message: ReplicaSet "kubernetes-dashboard-c7496bcf" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-08-10T08:22:21Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2018-08-10T08:22:21Z
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Comment: could you please provide results of kubectl get services and also post the dashboard.yaml?

Comment: @aurelius   Yes, I had posted for detail. thanks!

Comment: The config side seems to be fine. Can you please tell me how do you try to access the dashboard and on which address and port? Did you follow some tutorial? 
Also you can check my answer on accessing the dashboard - maybe it would give you some hints, before we can get enough information to help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253016/k8s-dashboard-not-logging-in-k8s-version-1-11/51270399#51270399

Comment: @aurelius Thank you for your help, I read your link in detail and try it，but it did't work for me，I access the dashboard: ```http://192.168.2.86:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/login ```  ， after got token and apply the token in browser，unable login and does not display any error messages

Comment: @aurelius  The issue has been sloved, thank you again

Comment: I have the same problem.How can I solve it?